# Why isn't this overlay for mousemove disappearing on mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a skyblue rectangle. When the mouse moves inside the skyblue rectangle, a smaller rectangle moves with the mouse. When the mouse leaves the area, the smaller rectangle should disappear, but sometimes it continues showing.

I don't see anything with the code. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#div1").on("mousemove", function(e) {
    $("#div2").css({
      "display": "inline",
      "left": e.clientX,
      "top": e.clientY
    });
  })
  $("#div1").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $("#div2").hide();
  })
})
```

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px
}
#div2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 35px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
#div2 p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <p>mouse</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without testing the code ... but you should probably use "mouseenter" and not "mousemove", which keep active when ..., well, you move the mouse.

Comment: @HansMeiser That's deliberate because the `#div2` moves when the mouse does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you're seeing is because your mouse hasn't left `#div1`, due to being over `#div2`, which is a child of `#div1`.

Since `#div2` is `position: fixed;`, you needn't have it as a child of `#div1`. Although it would be possible to check that `e.clientX` or `e.clientY` is outside of the actual skyblue rectangle of `#div1` and use that as a triggering event, it would be simpler to move `#div2` out of `#div1` in the DOM, like so:

```
<div id="div1">

</div>
<div id="div2">
  <p style="font-size:3px;margin:0px 2px;">mouse</p>
</div>
```

Code snippet below shows this working in action.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#div1").on("mousemove", function(e) {
    $("#div2").css({
      "display": "inline",
      "left": e.clientX,
      "top": e.clientY
    });
  })
  $("#div1").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $("#div2").hide();
  })
})
```

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 35px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">

</div>
<div id="div2">
  <p style="font-size:3px;margin:0px 2px;">mouse</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Snippet appears to do nothing. Firefox 43.0

Comment: Nope, nothing changed. I've also seen it work in Firefox 47. If you ever find out what was wrong, let me know. @DarrenH

Answer (score 0):

This uses css to show/hide the div, and js to move the div to the cursor:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");

    div2.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
    div2.style.top  = e.clientY + "px";
});
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: skyblue;
}

#div2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 35px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size:3px;
    display: none;
}
    
#div1:hover + #div2 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2">mouse</div>
```

Comment: And how does this answer the question with the JS code?

Comment: this is just like hide() in jQuery,but it's not working.I don't know if it's because the broswer has some delay in acquring the coordinates.

Comment: No, how does your answer replies to the question? What is it solving in the original op code?

Comment: @TheProHands It has JS, now.